# Convert a string to shape

Tags: c#, wpf, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to make a game in C# and for that I need to know how do I change a string to a form, in my case a ellipse. I tried with:

```
int row1 = 1;
string var2 = "ell_1_" + row1;
Ellipse var1 = Convert.ChangeType(var2, Ellipse);
var1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
row1++;
```

The ellipse's names are `ell_1_1`, `ell_1_2`, and so on. The Ellipses are still made. It's a Wpf-Application.

Comment: How does a string relate to a shape? There's nothing in the string that can convert to a shape, like its position and focal points for example... Its like saying "I want to convert grass into steel", unless the grass is covered with iron and other metals required, it just won't happen.

Comment: WPF, Winforms, something else?

Comment: Ae you trying to make an elipse whose name (or variable) is `ell_1_x`?

Comment: has the ellipse be created first, or is it already existing? please be more specific!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Easy as this:

```
int row1 = 1;
string var2 = "ell_1_" + row1;
Ellipse var1 = Controls.Find(var2, true)[0] as Ellipse;
var1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
row1++;
```

Comment: if something does not fit to you, please add a comment, so I can edit it, please!

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions, like the ellipse already exists, that its WPF (although I would bet it is), and that Controls.Find will return the value (I see a `NullReferenceException` here at the very least). Also Controls.Find is Winforms, and doesn't mix with WPF.

Comment: @RonBeyer I tested it within my winforms control using a `Label` instead of `Ellipse`, and it worked fine. Nobody said, that it was not created or it has to be created?!

Comment: Ellipse is not a control in WinForms, only in WPF.

Comment: @RonBeyer and he didn't add a WPF tag, so I where should I know this from?

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm using a Ellipse in my WinForms! You just have to add a reference to the dll?!

Comment: Thanks for that, but how does this work in a WPF-Form?